# How to search related article page in sitecore

Tags: content-search

I have an `ArticlePage` template with a `TopicTags` field, which is a `treelist` pointing to a list of tags. Users can select one or two tags. I have a requirement to search for two related articles that are also of the '`ArticlePage`' type and have at least one matching tag from the current article page. I have the following code, but I couldn't make it work - looks like the `TopicTags` field ToString does not produce Guid1|Guid2.

thanks for your help!

BTW, this link does not work:
[adding-a-property-field-to-an-index](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/93/sitecore-experience-commerce/adding-a-property-field-to-an-index.html)

```csharp
var indexName = String.Format("sitecore_{0}_index", Sitecore.Context.Database.Name);
ISearchIndex selectedIndex = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex(indexName);
using (var context = selectedIndex.CreateSearchContext())
{
  var currentPageTags = new List<string>(); 

  tags = (MultilistField)pageItem.Fields["TopicTags"];

  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tags.Value)) {
    var tokens = tags.Value.Split(new char[] { '|' });
    foreach (var token in tokens) { 
       currentPageTags.Add(token);
    }
  }
  var searchFolder = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem("/sitecore/content/fedpartnership/home/pages");

  var searchResults = context.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>()
      .Where(x => x.Paths.Contains(searchFolder.ID) 
         && string.Compare(x.TemplateName, "ArticlePage", true ) == 0 
         && x.Name != pageItem.Name
         && (x.Fields["TopicTags"].ToString().Contains(currentPageTags[0])
            || currentPageTags.Count == 2 && x.Fields["TopicTags"].ToString().Contains(currentPageTags[1])));
```

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912476/using-c-sharp-to-check-if-string-contains-a-string-in-string-array . You need a similar logic like,  CurrentTagsArray = [guid1, guid2] and stringToMatch = "guid2|guid3"

Comment: Just few correction in your code - 1) You need NOT operator in 3rd line 2) Check spelling of template name in last line, it is 'ArcticlePage' now.

Comment: Please use the index for queries like this instead of searching through the Sitecore database...

Comment: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/13351/contentsearch-predicates-for-filtering-on-a-multilist-field does not solve my problem